# Android - Attempting to update views using MVVM and view data bindings

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, view, binding

I'm pretty new to the MVVM design pattern and on top of that, I've only been using Kotlin for a couple days, so I apologize if the solution is obvious.

I'm making an api call using retrofit and observing the live data in my **MainActivity.**.

```
viewModel.balance.observe(this, Observer {balance ->
        Log.d( "MainActivity", "${balance}")
        updateViews(balance)
    })
```

This is my update view function in **MainActivity**.

```
private fun updateViews(balance: Balance){
    viewModel.balanceBinding = balance.balance
    viewModel.currencyBinding = balance.currency
}
```

And my **ViewModel**.

```
class BalanceViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _auth: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

var balanceBinding: String? = "$"
var currencyBinding: String? = null

val balance: LiveData<Balance> = Transformations
    .switchMap(_auth){auth ->
        BalanceRepository.getBalance(auth)
    }

fun setAuth(auth: String){
    val update = auth
    if(_auth.value == update){
        return
    }
    _auth.value = update
}

fun cancelJobs(){
    BalanceRepository.cancelJobs()
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't seem like the view update is working. I have verified that the api is indeed getting a response, and the bindings are working because if I change the values in the view model from null to for example "$", when I run the app the text view is the changed.

This might not be the right way of doing this, here to learn. 
Thank you in advance.

[EDIT] 
So after some testing, I've found that setting the text view with setText() works fine, so the issue is my binding. On some other posts, I've seen that because object isn't live data, it could not be updating. Gonna keep trying different things

Comment: You have two options if you're using data binding, you can either bind to livedata and it will auto-update so long as you've set yourBinding.lifeCycleOwner, or you can bind to something else like a regular Int or Bool or whatever, and then after updating it, do yourBinding.executePendingBindings()

Comment: I have also faced with the same issue. The real problem is about `balance` variable in your case. To 'fix' the issue, try to replace `Transformations.switchMap` related stuff with just only `_auth`. Then in your observer (in `MainActivity.kt` file) try to convert it as suits to your demands. That should work. Don't hesitate to ask your questions. If this solution helps to you, tell me it and I will post this as answer to the question.